# helm chart with dependency: how to package properly

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a parent helm chart with some child chart defined as a dependency in requirements.yaml. Child chart is packaged and uploaded to some-repo.

Currently I'm doing:

- run `helm package parent-chart`
- upload parent-chart.tgz to some-repo

And when I'm trying to install via `helm install some-repo/parent-chart`
I get only parent chart installed but not the child chart.

How do I need to package parent chart to be able to install it with the child chart together?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One additional step should be added:

```
helm dep update parent-chart
```

it places child-chart.tgz into chart folder of parent chart and then packaging works

Answer (score 3):

You can now do this via

```sh
helm package --dependency-update parent-chart
```

and save yourself the separate line suggested by the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

As @jeremysprofile has already pointed out, with Helm 3 you can do the following:

```bash
# Navigate to the root of my parent chart
cd path/where/my/chartyml/is

# package my chart (-u being the shorthand for --dependency-update)
helm package -u .
```

This should:

1. if it is not already existing, create a chart/ folder within your project root which contains all the child charts (as .tgz) defined as dependencies within the chart.yml of the parent chart.
2. create a `my-chart-name-as-defined-in-chartyml.tgz` in the root of the parent chart, which contains pretty much everything in that parent chart directory, except the things defined in your `.helmignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

Follow full [helm chart dependencies SDLC flow](https://www.rokpoto.com/helm-charts-ci-cd-chart-dependencies/#helm-charts-sdlc-in-the-context-of-dependencies) in order to avoid failures in CI/CD pipelines.